# How to implement an angle detecting swipe gesture recognizer in SceneKit?

Tags: swift, scenekit, uiswipegesturerecognizer

What I basically want to do is allow a user to swipe on their screen in any forward facing direction to launch a projectile at a target in that direction. I did look over UISwipeGestureRecognizer but I wasn't able to figure out how to implement one that allows swiping in any angle while also allowing me to determine the angle to launch the projectile.

Answer (score 1):

See the "Methods for Subclasses" section of the UIGestureRecognizer class doc. You should be able to override touchesBegan/Moved/Ended in your UISwipeGestureRecognizer subclass, and determine the angle to launch.